# Wordpress auto add port to url

Tags: wordpress, docker

I am creating a website with wordpress to run on docker. When I change the fields of the wordpress address and site address from the ip "http:/ip:port/example" to "http://example.com/example", when I access it from the browser, it adds automatically the port to the address like this "http://example.com:port/example", breaking the page. How can I solve this?